# Jquery multiple actions on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

To configure a burger navigation, I'm trying to perform 2 changes from one condition. I'm getting the following error :

> SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression

My code is as follows :

```
    $(".burger").on("click", function() {
    "20px" == $(".main-navigation").css("left") ? $(".navbarWrap").css("z-index", "-1"), $(".main-navigation").animate({
        left: "100%"
    }, 200) : $(".navbarWrap").css("z-index", "1"), $(".main-navigation").animate({
        left: "20px"
    }, 200)
})
```

Any idea where my error is ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try enclosing your multiple events as one in parentheses?

Comment: Yes, it works with parentheses, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".burger").on("click", function() {
"20px" == $(".main-navigation").css("left") ? ($(".navbarWrap").css("z-index", "-1"), $(".main-navigation").animate({
    left: "100%"
}, 200)) : ($(".navbarWrap").css("z-index", "1"), $(".main-navigation").animate({
    left: "20px"
}, 200))
});
```

You need to wrap the if else outputs in `()`